# how to save feature matrix as csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, image-processing

I have several features of Image and after image pre-processing I have plenty of data which I need to use frequently in future works. So to save time I want to save the data of image features in csv format. The following image features are the row attributes: Intensity, Skewness, Kurtosis, Std_deviation Max5, Min5.

Here every image feature is a numpy array of size (34560,1).

How to make a csv file which consists of all these image features.

Comment: So you have six numpy array of 34560 for each row attribute? And you want to save that to a single csv file?

Comment: If you have arbitrary objects, it's easiest to `pickle` them, the Python word for serialization. If in your case all are Numpy arrays you can use `np.save` or `np.savez` to put them away without the complication of reading them in  from .csv and reconverting them to np.arrays in the future. `np.load` brings them back.

Comment: @Sung I have total 80 features per voxel of an image and one label i.e. total 81 attributes and each attributes is a numpy column array of size 176526x1. I want to save them in a single file to save time so that I need not to calculate them every time.

Comment: @roadrunner66: Do you mean I should save each attribute separately using np.save and reuse them my np.load. Actually data is huge and this is very hectic to use np.save or np.load for 81 different attributes every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html) if you want to include attribute name to numpy array. But that will make things a bit more complicated to use. I would rather save the numpy array with same types and save the attributes name somewhere else. That is more straight forward and easier to use.

Example: For the sake of simplicity, let's say that you have three col arrays of length 4: a, b, c

```
a -> array([[1],
           [2],
           [3],
           [4]])

a.shape -> (4,1)
```

b and c array have same array shape.

For the sake of faster access to the data, it would be better to make that as a row array so that it is stored continuously on the disk and memory when loaded.

```
a = a.ravel(); b = b.ravel(); c = c.ravel()
a - > array([1, 2, 3, 4])
a.shape -> (4,)
```

Then, you stack them into a large array and save it to csv file.

```
x = np.vstack((a,b,c))
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8],
       [9, 10, 11, 12]])
x.shape -> (3,4)
```

Then, just save this stacked array to csv file.

```
np.savetxt('out.csv', x, delimiter=',')
```

This can be done in one line:

```
np.savetxt('out.csv', np.vstack(a.ravel(), b.ravel(), c.ravel()), delimiter='x')
```

Comment: Thanks Sung. How to add the attribute names. Because I have huge data and if i save the data without header then it will be so confusing for me that which column represent what feature.

Comment: In that case you have to use structured array. I posted link in my earlier posting.

Answer (score 0):

For example if yo got your out put into a variable "result" then you can save that result  in csv format using the below commands

```
import pandas as pd
result = "......................"(your expression)
result1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':result[:,0],'col2':result[:,1]})
result1.to_csv('Myresult.csv', header = False)
```

in the place of "**Myresult**" you can mention your desire path of output. In my case it would be like "**C:\Users\dinesh.n\Desktop\Myresult.csv**".
I hope it clears your doubt if not please excuse me and correct me.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Above solution shows an error that __'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_csv'__ because my result is a numpy.ndarray of size [176256,81]. Another issue is I have an header also **81 header** like **energy, entropy etc**. then what would you like to suggest. Thanks